# Can I hit the dragon with towers while he's flying around the castle?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

In reference to the Summit map:

Playing solo and rushing back and forth from repairing my defenses to manning the appropriate ballistae is a bit more hectic than I'd like, but playing with friends increases the health of the dragon to such high levels that the battle is more of a long drawn-out war of tedium than it is fun and rewarding. As the apprentice, I generally wind up running around from tower to tower repairing rather than engaging the dragon, making the process even more arduous.

Is there any way I can place towers around the outside edge of the castle to shorten the length of the battle? If I build some apprentice towers on the edge of the castle, facing outward, will they hit the dragon as he flies past? Does it depend on range? Does it depend on missile speed?

Comment: Buy a flamewarder from someone (the weapon you get for beating summit on hard) with high max level, and upgrade its elemental attack all the way - you can easily do 75k+ DPS this way *(attack-upgrades don't affect elemental, so you can and should do this even for tower-based squires - in fact, there is no reason to ever upgrade attack on a squire)*.  We played with four on insane, with two staying behind to heal towers.  With only two attacking it we were able to kill the dragon by the third time it stood near the castle.  It would go even faster with [good huntresses](http://goo.gl/3ziiV).

Comment: I do not know about the towers, but I do know if you team up with a squire you should not have to spend much time healing the turrets (I spent no time healing them actually) making this level much more fun to chase after the dragon.

Comment: I think the only tower with the range to hit the dragon is probably the strike tower.  The dragon moves quite fast and is rather far from most of the walls.  Its almost not worth putting that much DU in the hopes of getting the dragon as its much faster to get an ally and take it out the normal way.  And yes, missile speed will matter, anything slow moving will miss as he zooms by quite fast and the towers don't lead their shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Towers will indeed hit him, but his fireballs can easily take them out, so unless you're going for Master Strategist(award for only using towers in a level), it would probably end up just as tedious.